# WinForms Custom 3 Button Cell

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have a custom DatagridViewCell that has 3 clickable buttons horizontally. I have gotten as far as I can in code as shown below but I need a way to display the 3 buttons in the cell. I have only been able to paint text so far. I have even tried to declare a Panel object in case that will be easier to manipulate the buttons with.

```
public partial class CustomButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
{
private Panel buttonPanel;
private Button editButton;
private Button deleteButton;
private Button approveButton;
private Button cancelButton;
public bool Enabled { get; set; }

public CustomButtonCell()
{
    this.buttonPanel = new Panel();
    this.editButton = new Button();
    this.deleteButton = new Button();
    this.approveButton = new Button();
    this.cancelButton = new Button();

    this.editButton.Text = "Edit";
    this.deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
    this.approveButton.Text = "Approve";
    this.cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";

    this.buttonPanel.Controls.Add(this.editButton);
    this.buttonPanel.Controls.Add(this.deleteButton);
    this.buttonPanel.Controls.Add(this.approveButton);
    this.buttonPanel.Controls.Add(this.cancelButton);
    this.Enabled = true;
}

// Override the Clone method so that the Enabled property is copied.
public override object Clone()
{
    CustomButtonCell cell = (CustomButtonCell )base.Clone();
    cell.Enabled = this.Enabled;
    return cell;
}

protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
       Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
       DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value,
       object formattedValue, string errorText,
       DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
       DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
       DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
    // Call the base class method to paint the default cell appearance.
    base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState,
        value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
        advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

    // Calculate the area in which to draw the button.
    Rectangle buttonArea1 = cellBounds;
    Rectangle buttonAdjustment = this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
    buttonArea1.X += buttonAdjustment.X;
    buttonArea1.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y;
    buttonArea1.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height;
    buttonArea1.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width;
    Rectangle buttonArea2 = cellBounds;
    Rectangle buttonAdjustment2 = this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
    buttonArea2.X += buttonAdjustment2.X + buttonArea1.Width;
    buttonArea2.Y += buttonAdjustment2.Y;
    buttonArea2.Height -= buttonAdjustment2.Height;
    buttonArea2.Width -= buttonAdjustment2.Width;
    Rectangle buttonArea3 = cellBounds;
    Rectangle buttonAdjustment3 = this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
    buttonArea3.X += buttonAdjustment3.X + buttonArea2.Width;
    buttonArea3.Y += buttonAdjustment3.Y;
    buttonArea3.Height -= buttonAdjustment3.Height;
    buttonArea3.Width -= buttonAdjustment3.Width;
    Rectangle buttonArea4 = cellBounds;
    Rectangle buttonAdjustment4 = this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
    buttonArea4.X += buttonAdjustment4.X + buttonArea3.Width;
    buttonArea4.Y += buttonAdjustment4.Y;
    buttonArea4.Height -= buttonAdjustment4.Height;
    buttonArea4.Width -= buttonAdjustment4.Width;
    // Draw the disabled button.
    ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea1, PushButtonState.Default);
    ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea2, PushButtonState.Default);
    ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea3, PushButtonState.Default);
    ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea4, PushButtonState.Default);

    // Draw the disabled button text.

    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Test", this.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea1, SystemColors.GrayText);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Test", this.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea2, SystemColors.GrayText);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Test", this.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea3, SystemColors.GrayText);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Test", this.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea4, SystemColors.GrayText);


}

// Force the cell to repaint itself when the mouse pointer enters it.
protected override void OnMouseEnter(int rowIndex)
{
   
}

// Force the cell to repaint itself when the mouse pointer leaves it.
protected override void OnMouseLeave(int rowIndex)
{
   
}

}

public class CustomButtonColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
public CustomButtonColumn()
{
    this.CellTemplate = new CustomButtonCell ();
}
}
```

Comment: You should not need the controls. Painting the buttons like you do should be sufficient. What do you mean by manipulating the button? If you got them painted all you need is now handling the cell click and deciding which painted button has been clicked right?

Comment: @Ralf thanks for taking a look, you are almost right. The paint is not looking how I expected it. They do not respect the cell bounds and are overlapping the entire DataGrid. So i need a bit of help getting the 3 buttons painted in a way that respects the cell bounds

Comment: Do you actually need three buttons in one column? It might be way easier to use 3 columns with 1 button each. Then the dimensions for the buttons are obvious and cellclick  == buttonclick

Comment: Good point there, i think i will take that approach then. The use case behind it was too have a actions column with 3 buttons,  to take an action on that data item

Comment: @IVSoftware I see, we can collaborate on this example. Perhaps making it very dirt simple to prove the point of custom cell printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that sometimes there's a solid use case to display a `UserControl` whether it's "three buttons" or each row having its own rolling `Chart` of real time data or whatever! One approach that long-term has worked for me, tried and true, is having a  `DataGridViewUserControlColumn` class similar to the one coded below that can host a control in the cell bounds instead of just drawing one.

The theory of operation is to allow the bound data class to have properties that derive from `Control`. The corresponding auto-generated column(s) in the DGV can be swapped out. Then, when a `DataGridViewUserControlCell` gets "painted" instead of drawing the cell what happens instead is that the control is moved (if necessary) so that its bounds coincide with the cell bounds being drawn. Since the user control is in the DataGridView.Controls collection, the UC stays on top in the z-order and paints the same as any child of any container would.

[image: screenshot]

The item's UserControl is added to the `DataGridView.Controls` collection the first time it's drawn and removed when the cell's `DataGridView` property is set to null (e.g. when user deletes a row). When the `AllowUserToAddRows` options is enabled, the "new row" list item doesn't show a control until the item editing is complete.

---

**Typical Record class**

```
class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Record()
    {
        Modes.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
        Actions.Click += (sender, e) =>
            { _ = execTask(); };
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get => $"{Modes.Text} : {_description}";
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_description, value))
            {
                _description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _description = string.Empty;

    #region B O U N D    C O N T R O L S    o f    A N Y    T Y P E   
    public ButtonCell3Up Modes { get; } = new ButtonCell3Up();
    public ProgressBar Actions { get; } = new ProgressBar { Value = 1 };  
    #endregion B O U N D    C O N T R O L S    o f    A N Y    T Y P E   

    private async Task execTask()
    {
        Actions.Value = 0;
        while(Actions.Value < Actions.Maximum)
        {
            await Task.Delay(250);
            Actions.Value++;
        }
    }
    private void onModesTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

**Configure DGV**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;
        dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
        dataGridView.MouseDoubleClick += onMouseDoubleClick;  

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Records.Add(new Record()); // <- Auto-configure columns
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Modes)].Width = 200;
        DataGridViewUserControlColumn.Swap(dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Modes)]);
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Actions)].Width = 200;
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Actions)].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(5);
        DataGridViewUserControlColumn.Swap(dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Actions)]);
        Records.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        
        // FOR DEMO PURPOSES: Add some items.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Voltage Range" });
            Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Current Range" });
            Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Power Range" });
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= Records.Count; i++)
            Records[i - 1].Modes.Labels = new[] { $"{i}A", $"{i}B", $"{i}C", }; 
}
```

---

**Custom Cell with Paint override**

```
public class DataGridViewUserControlCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    private Control _control = null;
    private DataGridViewUserControlColumn _column;
    public override Type FormattedValueType => typeof(string);
    private DataGridView _dataGridView = null;
    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
    {
        base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
        if((DataGridView == null) && (_dataGridView != null))
        {
            // WILL occur on Swap() and when a row is deleted.
            if (TryGetControl(out var control))
            {
                _column.RemoveUC(control);
            }
        }
        _dataGridView = DataGridView;
    }
    protected override void Paint(
        Graphics graphics,
        Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds,
        int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
        object value,
        object formattedValue,
        string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(getBackColor(@default: Color.Azure)))
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(brush, cellBounds);
        }
        if (DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].IsNewRow)
        {   /* G T K */
        }
        else
        {
            if (TryGetControl(out var control))
            {
                SetLocationAndSize(cellBounds, control);
            }
        }
        Color getBackColor(Color @default)
        {
            if((_column != null) && (_column.DefaultCellStyle != null))
            {
                Style = _column.DefaultCellStyle;
            }
            return Style.BackColor.A == 0 ? @default : Style.BackColor;
        }
    }
    public void SetLocationAndSize(Rectangle cellBounds, Control control, bool visible = true)
    {
        control.Location = new Point(
            cellBounds.Location.X +
            Style.Padding.Left,
            cellBounds.Location.Y + Style.Padding.Top);
        control.Size = new Size(
            cellBounds.Size.Width - (Style.Padding.Left + Style.Padding.Right),
            cellBounds.Height - (Style.Padding.Top + Style.Padding.Bottom));
        control.Visible = visible;
    }
    public bool TryGetControl(out Control control)
    {
        control = null;
        if (_control == null)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((RowIndex != -1) && (RowIndex < DataGridView.Rows.Count))
                {
                    var row = DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex];
                    _column = (DataGridViewUserControlColumn)DataGridView.Columns[ColumnIndex];
                    var record = row.DataBoundItem;
                    var type = record.GetType();
                    var pi = type.GetProperty(_column.Name);
                    control = (Control)pi.GetValue(record);
                    if (control.Parent == null)
                    {
                        DataGridView.Controls.Add(control);
                        _column.AddUC(control);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
            }
            _control = control;
        }
        else control = _control;
        return _control != null;
    }
}
```

---

**Custom Column**

```
public class DataGridViewUserControlColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewUserControlColumn() => CellTemplate = new DataGridViewUserControlCell();
    public static void Swap(DataGridViewColumn old)
    {
        var dataGridView = old.DataGridView;
        var indexB4 = old.Index;
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(indexB4);
        dataGridView.Columns.Insert(indexB4, new DataGridViewUserControlColumn
        {
            Name = old.Name,
            AutoSizeMode = old.AutoSizeMode,
            Width = old.Width,
            DefaultCellStyle = old.DefaultCellStyle,
        });
    }
    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
    {
        base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
        if ((DataGridView == null) && (_dataGridView != null))
        {
            _dataGridView.Invalidated -= (sender, e) => refresh();
            _dataGridView.Scroll -= (sender, e) => refresh();
            _dataGridView.SizeChanged -= (sender, e) => refresh();
            foreach (var control in _controls.ToArray())
            {
                RemoveUC(control);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DataGridView.Invalidated += (sender, e) =>refresh();
            DataGridView.Scroll += (sender, e) =>refresh();
            DataGridView.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>refresh();
        }
        _dataGridView = DataGridView;
    }
    // Keep track of controls added by this instance
    // so that they can be removed by this instance.
    private readonly List<Control> _controls = new List<Control>();
    internal void AddUC(Control control)
    {
        _controls.Add(control);
        DataGridView.Controls.Add(control);
    }
    internal void RemoveUC(Control control)
    {
        _controls.Remove(control);
        if (_dataGridView != null)
        {
            _dataGridView.Controls.Remove(control);
        }
    }
    int _wdtCount = 0;
    private void refresh()
    {
        var capture = ++_wdtCount;
        // Allow changes to settle.
        Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() => 
            {
                if (DataGridView != null)
                {
                    foreach (var row in DataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[Index] is DataGridViewUserControlCell cell)
                        {
                            if (row.IsNewRow)
                            {   /* G T K */
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var cellBounds = DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex, true);
                                if (cell.TryGetControl(out var control))
                                {
                                    cell.SetLocationAndSize(cellBounds, control, visible: !row.IsNewRow);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    private DataGridView _dataGridView = null;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/datagridviewcell-with-three-horizontal-buttons.git) the demo code.

Comment: Taking a look at this. I am wondering how the Record object turns into a control, and how i can adapt it. But this is exactly the kind of idea i was going for, i needed to have a column like this based on business

Comment: Ok i think i see it now, if i follow this correctly the Record stores a retail button and in painting you add the buttonup control right in the cell? Poor am i missing something. I am very intrigued by this been stuck on it since last week, I'm invested! Lol

Comment: Yes exactly! btw there's a little tweak I need to make to this code example, but that's the basic idea of the thing. The `Control` property is a control from the start, but adding it to `dataGridView.Controls` gives it a drawable native window handle. And being a child control of DGV keeps it on top.

Comment: So it adds controls and manipulates the cell space to accommodate the child controls.  Can ButtonCell3Up be replaced with any other control?

Comment: Indeed yes, should work for any property derived from `Control`.

Comment: Interesting, and very flexible compared to what I was doing.